# SwiftUI: Global Overlay That Can Be Triggered From Any View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm quite new to the SwiftUI framework and I haven't wrapped my head around all of it yet so please bear with me.

Is there a way to trigger an "overlay view" from inside "another view" when its binding changes? See illustration below:

[image]

I figure this "overlay view" would wrap all my views. I'm not sure how to do this yet - maybe using `ZIndex`. I also guess I'd need some sort of callback when the binding changes, but I'm also not sure how to do that either.

This is what I've got so far:

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var liked: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LikeButton(liked: $liked)
        }
    }
}
```

**LikeButton**

```
struct LikeButton : View {
    @Binding var liked: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.toggleLiked() }) {
            Image(systemName: liked ? "heart" : "heart.fill")
        }
    }

    private func toggleLiked() {
        self.liked = !self.liked
        // NEED SOME SORT OF TOAST CALLBACK HERE
    }
}
```

I feel like I need some sort of callback inside my `LikeButton`, but I'm not sure how this all works in Swift.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want an overlay to be placed whenever the `LikeButton` is tapped?

Comment: @RPatel99 Yeah.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It's quite easy - and entertaining - to build a "toast" in SwiftUI!

Let's do it!

```swift
struct Toast<Presenting>: View where Presenting: View {

    /// The binding that decides the appropriate drawing in the body.
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    /// The view that will be "presenting" this toast
    let presenting: () -> Presenting
    /// The text to show
    let text: Text

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in

            ZStack(alignment: .center) {

                self.presenting()
                    .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)

                VStack {
                    self.text
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2,
                       height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                .background(Color.secondary.colorInvert())
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .transition(.slide)
                .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Explanation of the body:

- `GeometryReader` gives us the preferred size of the superview , thus allowing the perfect sizing for our `Toast`.
- `ZStack` stacks views on top of each other.
- The logic is trivial: if the toast is not supposed to be seen (`isShowing == false`), then we render the `presenting` view. If the toast has to be presented (`isShowing == true`), then we render the `presenting` view with a little bit of blur - because we can - and we create our toast next.
- The toast is just a `VStack` with a `Text`, with custom frame sizing, some design bells and whistles (colors and corner radius), and a default `slide` transition.

I added this method on `View` to make the `Toast` creation easier:

```swift
extension View {

    func toast(isShowing: Binding<Bool>, text: Text) -> some View {
        Toast(isShowing: isShowing,
              presenting: { self },
              text: text)
    }

}
```

And a little demo on how to use it:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showToast: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<100) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("A List"), displayMode: .large)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showToast.toggle()
                }
            }){
                Text("Toggle toast")
            })
        }
        .toast(isShowing: $showToast, text: Text("Hello toast!"))
    }

}
```

I used a `NavigationView` to make sure the view fills the entire screen, so the `Toast` is sized and positioned correctly.

The `withAnimation` block ensures the `Toast` transition is applied.

---

**How it looks**:

[image]

It's easy to extend the `Toast` with the power of SwiftUI DSL.

The `Text` property can easily become a `@ViewBuilder` closure to accomodate the most extravagant of the layouts.

---

**To add it to your content view**:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var liked: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LikeButton(liked: $liked)
        }
        // make it bigger by using "frame" or wrapping it in "NavigationView"
        .toast(isShowing: $liked, text: Text("Hello toast!"))
    }
}
```

---

**How to hide the toast afte 2 seconds (as requested)**:

Append this code after `.transition(.slide)` in the toast `VStack`.

```swift
.onAppear {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
      withAnimation {
        self.isShowing = false
      }
    }
}
```

**Tested on Xcode 11.1**

Comment: Any idea how to hide the toast after 2 seconds? Is there some sort of timeout function in Swift?

Comment: @realph added as the last section in the answer - you can simply set `isShowing` to false, using `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter`

Comment: You're a star! I'm going to try and unpack this tomorrow, but glad to have it working at this point. Thanks again.

Comment: So it looks like SwiftUI automatically applies a cross fade animation when switching between views, and it looks like the screen flickers white before the toast appears. Any idea how to turn that off? Sorry for so many questions, I've tried google-ing it but haven't been able to find a thing.

Comment: Ahh. So it looks like they reference it in the tutorials here. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions

> By default, views transition on- and offscreen by fading in and out. You can customize this transition by using the transition(_:) modifier.

I'll see if I can play around with that `transition(_:)` modifier and report back

Comment: @realph to disable the fade-in / fade-out animation, use `.transition(.identity)`

Comment: Sorry for all the questions. Is there an easy way to not show the toast on the initial value? If I navigate to the view the toast is shown by default, and I guess I only want to the toast to show if the button is toggled.

Comment: One little thing: In XCode 11 Beta4 the .onAppear() seems to get called only once, with its first appearance. Some kind of deinitialization needed after first toggle?

Comment: Due to .onAppear() gets called only once on the first appearance, you need to replace it with:

`var body: some View {
        
        if self.isShowing {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.isShowing = false
            }
        }

        return GeometryReader { ..........`

Comment: How do I get this to work when I *do not have access* to a view that fills the entire screen? I want to do this, as the question postulates, from *any view*, namely a child view that only fills a fraction of the screen. How is this possible? With the given solution, you must have access to the base view for this to work.

Comment: @NoahWilder One way would be to put the toast on your root view, And then have children wired up so they could modify some state the root uses which would trigger the toast

Comment: My problem is that I want to trigger the global overlay/alert from an isolated subview that has no knowledge nor access to its parent view @guptron.

Comment: Right this is an architectural question which can be solved in many ways. It’s probably worth a separate question. Redux is one pattern that can solve this.

Comment: if a toast is made to show more than once , it does not automatically disappear @MatteoPacini

Comment: @MatteoPacini cloud you also build a banner system like [this](https://trailingclosure.com/notification-banner-using-swiftui/) based on your method? The view modifiers used there do not seem to work on list views or navigation views :(

Comment: Why using `let presenting: () -> Presenting` instead of `let presenting: Presenting`

Comment: The View extension allowing this to be attached to the view with the postfix grammar is superb.

Comment: This is a great way to show the toast. The view disappearing part was not working for me. But I added the same (Not .onAppear, but asyncAfter part only) in my main view after when I have changed the showToast boolean to true.

Comment: This solution comes with a precondition: the modifier must be under the page view. For example, it can not be put under a button or a small view on the screen.

Comment: Does this work on full screen covers also? Thanks!

Comment: Suppose you added it to a short bottom View, It will fail.

Answer (score 15):

I modified Matteo Pacini's great answer, above, incorporating comments to have the Toast fade in and fade out after a delay.  I also modified the View extension to be a bit more generic, and to accept a trailing closure similar to the way .sheet works.

ContentView.swift:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var lightsOn: Bool = false
    @State private var showToast: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                if (!self.showToast) {
                    self.lightsOn.toggle()

                    withAnimation {
                        self.showToast = true
                    }
                }
            }){
                Text("switch")
            } //Button
            .padding(.top)

            Image(systemName: self.lightsOn ? "lightbulb" : "lightbulb.fill")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .padding(.all)
                .toast(isPresented: self.$showToast) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Lights: \(self.lightsOn ? "ON" : "OFF")")
                        Image(systemName: self.lightsOn ? "lightbulb" : "lightbulb.fill")
                    } //HStack
                } //toast
        } //VStack
    } //body
} //ContentView
```

View+Toast.swift:

```
extension View {
    func toast<Content>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View where Content: View {
        Toast(
            isPresented: isPresented,
            presenter: { self },
            content: content
        )
    }
}
```

Toast.swift:

```
struct Toast<Presenting, Content>: View where Presenting: View, Content: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let presenter: () -> Presenting
    let content: () -> Content
    let delay: TimeInterval = 2

    var body: some View {
        if self.isPresented {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.delay) {
                withAnimation {
                    self.isPresented = false
                }
            }
        }

        return GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                self.presenter()

                ZStack {
                    Capsule()
                        .fill(Color.gray)

                    self.content()
                } //ZStack (inner)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 1.25, height: geometry.size.height / 10)
                .opacity(self.isPresented ? 1 : 0)
            } //ZStack (outer)
            .padding(.bottom)
        } //GeometryReader
    } //body
} //Toast
```

With this you could toast Text, or an Image (or both, as shown below), or any other View.

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! The previous solution was making the underlying view jump around for me, and this looks much nicer.

Comment: Won't work for sheet, sheet will hide it behind.

Answer (score 5):

## App-wide View

If you want it to be app-wide, put in somewhere app-wide! For example, you can add it to the `MyProjectApp.swift` (or in `sceneDelegate` for UIKit/AppDelegate projects) file like this:

<sub>**Note that** the button and the State are just for more explanation and you may consider changing them in the way you like</sub>

```
@main
struct SwiftUIAppPlaygroundApp: App {  // <- Note that where we are!
    @State var showToast = false

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Button("App-Wide Button") { showToast.toggle() }

            ZStack {
                ContentView() // <- The app flow

                if showToast {
                    MyCustomToastView().ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all) // <- App-wide overlays
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See? now you can add any sort of view on anywhere of the screen, *without blocking animations*. Just convert that @State to some sort of AppState like `Observable`s or `Environment`s and boom!  you did it!

**Note that** it is a demo, you should use an `environment` variable or smt to be able for changing it from outside of this view's body

Comment: Is there any way to make it works in front of sheet or fullScreenCover?

Comment: I used this method and it worked but whenever the state variable (showToast) changes, the app navigates back to the ContentView!

Comment: Sorry, but this approach does not work with sheet modifiers for example

Answer (score 4):

**here is the how to overlay on all of your views including NavigationView!**

create a class model to store your views!

```
class ParentView:ObservableObject {
    
        @Published var view:AnyView = AnyView(EmptyView())
        
    }
```

create the model in your parrent view and call it in your view hierarchy
pass this class to your environment object of your parent view

```
struct Example: View {
    @StateObject var parentView = ParentView()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            NavigationView{
                ChildView()
                    .environmentObject(parentView)
                    .navigationTitle("dynamic parent view")
            }
            parentView.view
        }
    }
}
```

from now on you can call parentview in your child view by

```
@EnvironmentObject var parentView:ParentView
```

then for example in your tap gesture, you can change the parent view and show a pop up that covers everything including your navigationviews

@StateObject var parentView = ParentView()

here is the full solution copy and play with it in your preview!

```
import SwiftUI

class ParentView:ObservableObject {
        @Published var view:AnyView = AnyView(EmptyView())
    }


struct example: View {
    @StateObject var parentView = ParentView()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            NavigationView{
                ChildView()
                    .environmentObject(parentView)
                    .navigationTitle("dynamic parent view")
            }
            parentView.view
        }
    }
}
struct ChildView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var parentView:ParentView

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Text("hello")
                .onTapGesture {
                    parentView.view = AnyView(Color.red.opacity(0.4).ignoresSafeArea())
                }
        }
    }
}

struct example_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        example()
    }
}
```

also you can improve this dramatically like this...!

```
struct ParentViewModifire:ViewModifier {
    @EnvironmentObject var parentView:ParentView

    @Binding var presented:Bool
    let anyView:AnyView
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: presented, perform: { value in
                if value {
                    parentView.view = anyView
                }
            })
    }
}
extension View {
     func overlayAll<Overlay>(_ overlay: Overlay, presented: Binding<Bool>) -> some View where Overlay : View {
        self
        .modifier(ParentViewModifire(presented: presented, anyView: AnyView(overlay)))
    }
}
```

now in your child view you can call this modifier on your view

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @State var newItemPopUp:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Text("hello")
               .overlayAll(newCardPopup, presented: $newItemPopUp)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not currently provide any APIs that allow you to make global views similar to their own alert pop-ups.

In fact these views are actually still using UIKit under the hood.

If you want your own global pop-ups you can sort of hack your own (note this isn't tested, but something very similar should work for global presentation of toasts):

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

/// Global class that will manage toasts
class ToastPresenter: ObservableObject {
    // This static property probably isn't even needed as you can inject via @EnvironmentObject
    static let shared: ToastPresenter = ToastPresenter()
    
    private init() {}
    
    @Published private(set) var isPresented: Bool = false
    private(set) var text: String?
    private var timer: Timer?
    
    /// Call this function to present toasts
    func presentToast(text: String, duration: TimeInterval = 5) {
        // reset the toast if one is currently being presented.
        isPresented = false
        self.text = nil
        timer?.invalidate()
        
        self.text = text
        isPresented = true
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: duration, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.isPresented = false
        }
    }
}


/// The UI for a toast
struct Toast: View {
    var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .padding()
            .background(Capsule().fill(Color.gray))
            .shadow(radius: 6)
            .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.default))
    }
}

extension View {
    /// ViewModifier that will present a toast when its binding changes
    @ViewBuilder func toast(presented: Binding<Bool>, text: String) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self
        
            if presented.wrappedValue {
                Toast(text: text)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
    }
}

/// The first view in your app's view hierarchy
struct RootView: View {
    @StateObject var toastPresenter = ToastPresenter.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        MyAppMainView()
            .toast(presented: $toastPresenter.isPresented, text: toastPresenter.text)
            // Inject the toast presenter into the view hierarchy
            .environmentObject(toastPresenter)
    }
}

/// Some view later on in the app
struct SomeViewDeepInTheHierarchy: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var toastPresenter: ToastPresenter
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            toastPresenter.presentToast(text: "Hello World")
        } label: {
            Text("Show Toast")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't work for sheet ahead. Sheet will cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.presentation()` to show an alert when the button is tapped.

In `LikeButton`:

```
@Binding var liked: Bool

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {self.liked = !self.liked}, label: {
        Image(systemName: liked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
    }).presentation($liked) { () -> Alert in
        Alert.init(title: Text("Thanks for liking!"))
    }
}
```

You can also use `.presentation()` to present other Modal views, like a `Popover` or `ActionSheet`. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button/3264325-presentation) and the "See Also" section on that page in Apple's SwiftUI documentation for info on the different `.presentation()` options.

**Edit**: Example of what you want with a custom view using `Popover`:

```
@State var liked = false
let popover = Popover(content: Text("Thanks for liking!").frame(width: 200, height: 100).background(Color.white), dismissHandler: {})
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {self.liked = !self.liked}, label: {
        Image(systemName: liked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
    }).presentation(liked ? popover : nil)
}
```

Comment: That's for a native alert, right? How would I render a custom view for the overlay?

Comment: @realph you would either want to provide presentation with a `Popover` or a `Modal`, both of which can be constructed with a custom `View`. `Popover` is probably what you are looking for based on your pictures.

Comment: @realph edited my answer to help you out a bit more with using `Popover`

Answer (score 0):

I am using this open source: https://github.com/huynguyencong/ToastSwiftUI . It is very simple to use.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingToast = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Button("Show toast") {
                self.isShowingToast = true
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()

        // Just add a modifier to show a toast, with binding variable to control
        .toast(isPresenting: $isShowingToast, dismissType: .after(3)) {
            ToastView(message: "Hello world!", icon: .info)
        }
    }
}
```