# Dismiss a SwiftUI View that is contained in a UIHostingController

Tags: ios, uikit, swiftui

I have rewritten my sign in view controller as a SwiftUI `View`. The `SignInView` is wrapped in a `UIHostingController` subclass (`final class SignInViewController: UIHostingController<SignInView> {}`), and is presented modally, full screen, when sign in is necessary.

Everything is working fine, except I can't figure out how to dismiss the `SignInViewController` from the `SignInView`. I have tried adding:

```
@Environment(\.isPresented) var isPresented
```

in `SignInView` and assigning it to `false` when sign in is successful, but this doesn't appear to interop with UIKit. How can I dismiss the view?

Comment: This seems like incorrect behaviour to me on the part of SwiftUI. I've opened an item in Apple's Feedback Assistant about this [here](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9116652).

Comment: It just occurred to me that bug reports which I create in Apple's Feedback Assistant are visible to me only and not visible to other developers. That's a shame. The bug report which I created describes how a `UIHostingController` object presented modally from a `UIViewController` cannot be dismissed programmatically by means of `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`. I've created a small, minimal UIKit application which demonstrates the problem [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/SwiftUIExperiments/tree/master/App2).

Comment: This issue is resolved in Xcode 13.0 beta 5. I tested it against an iPhone 15.0 simulator.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**UPDATE:** From the release notes of iOS 15 beta 1:

> isPresented, PresentationMode, and the new DismissAction action dismiss a hosting controller presented from UIKit. (52556186)

---

I ended up finding a much simpler solution than what was offered:

```swift
final class SettingsViewController: UIHostingController<SettingsView> {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: SettingsView())
        rootView.dismiss = dismiss
    }

    func dismiss() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    var dismiss: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Button("Dimiss", action: dismiss!)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why make the dismiss closure optional and then force unwrap it...

Comment: It's unreasonable to expect production ready code on SO. `dismiss` must be assigned after initialization because of `UIHostingController`'s requirements. The correct thing to do (mapping the optional to a button) is probably less readable for those newer to Swift and SwiftUI.

Comment: I understand. You could also just call the completed closure from within the closure of the button handler.

Comment: The problem with that is you can have a button that does nothing.

Comment: @jjatie How do you create the `SettingsViewController` since it's expecting the `NSCoder`?

Comment: @ricardopereira If you're using a storyboard, the you can use a segue action.

Comment: How do you call it programmatically? Not sure how to use the NSCoder

Comment: @fphelp you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: @fphelp, if you want to do it all programmatically (no storyboards, no nibs), then you'd have to do something like this:

```
private final class SettingsViewController: UIHostingController<SettingsView> {
    init() {
        super.init(rootView: SettingsView())
        rootView.dismiss = dismiss
    }

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func dismiss() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 58):

I found another approach that seems to work well and which feels a little cleaner than some of the other approaches. Steps:

1. Add a `dismissAction` property to the SwiftUI view:

```
struct SettingsUIView: View {
    var dismissAction: (() -> Void)
    ...
}
```

2. Call the `dismissAction` when you want to dismiss the view:

```
Button(action: dismissAction ) {
    Text("Done")
}
```

3. When you present the view, provide it with a dismissal handler:

```
let settingsView = SettingsUIView(dismissAction: {self.dismiss( animated: true, completion: nil )})
let settingsViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: settingsView )

present( settingsViewController, animated: true )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what best practice is, but I really like this answer and people who scroll down for it will be happy they did IMHO.  In my usage I've renamed dismissAction to onComplete and it takes an optional error.  This makes it very similar to how I like to handle dialogs that may complete with success or failure and allow the presenting host to dismiss it and handle the result appropriately.

Comment: With that approach you won't be able to dismiss the `settingsViewController`, only the parent view controller since it's using `self` inside the `dismissAction`.

Comment: Unsure why this is not the accepted answer. It's precise, brief and  in line with how a closure is normally used in swift in general to dismiss vc's.

Answer (score 16):

All the provided answers here didn't work for me, probably because of some weak reference. This is the solution I came up with:

**Creating the view and UIHostingController:**

```
let delegate = SheetDismisserProtocol()
let signInView = SignInView(delegate: delegate)
let host = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(signInView))
delegate.host = host
// Present the host modally
```

**SheetDismisserProtocol:**

```
class SheetDismisserProtocol: ObservableObject {
    weak var host: UIHostingController<AnyView>? = nil

    func dismiss() {
        host?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

**The view that has to be dismissed:**

```
struct SignInView: View {
    @ObservedObject var delegate: SheetDismisserProtocol

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.delegate.dismiss()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The `host` from `SheetDismisserProtocol` should be `weak`, if not then the `UIHostingController` instance will leak.

Comment: @ObservedObject is not necessary!

Comment: This method works. However my preview now gives an error - "Missing argument for parameter 'delegate' in call". Do you know how to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Just add the parameter to the init of the preview: `YourView(delegate: SheetDismisserProtocol())`.

Comment: thanks, the only solution that worked in my case

Comment: It gives this error for  delegate.host assignment
Cannot assign value of type 'UIHostingController<some View>' to type 'UIHostingController<AnyView>'

Comment: @OzgurSahin Did you cast the view to `AnyView` before passing it into the rootView of the hosting controller?

Comment: Yes I casted like same as in your example AnyView(signInView)

Answer (score 11):

Another approach (relatively easier in my opinion) would be to have an optional property type of `UIViewController` in your `SwiftUI` `view` and then set it to the viewController that will present `UIHostingController` which will be wrapping your `SwiftUI` view.

A simple SettingsView:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    var presentingVC: UIViewController?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.presentingVC?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
        }) {
            Text("Dismiss")
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you present this view from a view controller using `UIHostingController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private func presentSettingsView() {
        var view = SettingsView()
        view.presentingVC = self
        let hostingVC = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
        present(hostingVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Now as you can see in the action of the `Button` in `SettingsView`, we are going to talk to `ViewController` to dismiss the view controller it is presenting, which in our case will be the `UIHostingController` that wraps `SettingsView`.

Comment: I get the error: Instance member 'presentingVC' cannot be used on type 'SettingsView' when typing: SettingsView().presentingVC = self

Comment: This will cause the controller to leak memory as it'll have a cyclic dependency with the child view.

Comment: But how? `ViewController` does not have a reference to `SettingsView`, or the `UIHostingController` it presents. Then, `SettingsView` only keeps a reference to `ViewController`, not the `UIHostingController` it was added as a root view.

Did you try this out and observed the leak in the memory debugger? @thecoolwinter

Answer (score 8):

You could just use notifications.

**Swift 5.1**

In the SwiftUI button handler:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("dismissSwiftUI"), object: nil)
```

In the UIKit view controller:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("dismissSwiftUI"), object: nil, queue: nil) { (_) in
    hostingVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Does it matter where you put the observer? Whether it's in the classes init() or viewDidLoad()?

Comment: Not sure. I used viewDidLoad()

Comment: Please don't use NotificationCenter for this kind of situations. You can easily lose track of notifications you observe. It's an easy mechanism to broadcast information from one class to registered listeners and it's perfect for system wide notifications not for specific implementations like this.

Comment: simple way before fullScreenCover at iOS 14 

Comment: Agree with @ricardopereira a global notification is not the best tool to implement a a callback.

Comment: hmmm dont like this pattern, since in new UI , you can present more two views at the same time

Answer (score 7):

```
let rootView = SignInView();
let ctrl = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView);
ctrl.rootView.dismiss = {[weak ctrl] in
    ctrl?.dismiss(animated: true)
}
present(ctrl, animated:true, completion:nil);
```

pay attention:   ctrl.rootView.dismiss not rootView.dismiss

Comment: Does this not result in a strong reference cycle?

Comment: @re_zacks yes, corrected

Answer (score 6):

What about extend environment values with hosting controller presenter? It allows to be used like `presentationMode`, from any view in the hierarchy and it is easily reusable and scalable.
Define your new environment value:

```
struct UIHostingControllerPresenter {
    init(_ hostingControllerPresenter: UIViewController) {
        self.hostingControllerPresenter = hostingControllerPresenter
    }
    private unowned var hostingControllerPresenter: UIViewController
    func dismiss() {
        if let presentedViewController = hostingControllerPresenter.presentedViewController, !presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed { // otherwise an ancestor dismisses hostingControllerPresenter - which we don't want.
            hostingControllerPresenter.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

private enum UIHostingControllerPresenterEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: UIHostingControllerPresenter? = nil
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    /// An environment value that attempts to extend `presentationMode` for case where
    /// view is presented via `UIHostingController` so dismissal through
    /// `presentationMode` doesn't work.
    var uiHostingControllerPresenter: UIHostingControllerPresenter? {
        get { self[UIHostingControllerPresenterEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[UIHostingControllerPresenterEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Then pass the value when needed like:

```
let view = AnySwiftUIView().environment(\.uiHostingControllerPresenter, UIHostingControllerPresenter(self))
let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
...
```

And enjoy using

```
@Environment(\.uiHostingControllerPresenter) private var uiHostingControllerPresenter
...
uiHostingControllerPresenter?.dismiss()
```

where you otherwise go with

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
...
presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // .isPresented = false
```

Answer (score 5):

This was a bug in Xcode 12 (and most probably earlier versions of Xcode also). It has been resolved in Xcode 13.0 beta 5 and hopefully will continue to be resolved in the stable release of Xcode 13.0. That said, if you're able to build with Xcode 13 and target iOS 15 (or higher), then prefer the [EnvironmentValues.dismiss](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismiss) property over the deprecated [EnvironmentValues.presentationMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/presentationmode) property, as follows:

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss") { dismiss() }
    }
}
```

If you're not able to build with Xcode 13 and target iOS 15, then opt for one of the workarounds proposed in this thread.

Comment: The first part is correct, this was a bug pre-Xcode 13. `PresentationMode` is now deprecated however. The accepted answer is updated with this information.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the [EnvironmentValues.presentationMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/presentationmode) property and the [PresentationMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/presentationmode) structure are deprecated in iOS 15. I did not realise that. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and thanks to this post, I could write a mixed solution, to improve usability of the solutions of this post :

```swift
final class RootViewController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<AnyView> {
    init(rootView: Content) {
        let dismisser = ControllerDismisser()
        let view = rootView
            .environmentObject(dismisser)

        super.init(rootView: AnyView(view))

        dismisser.host = self
    }

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

final class ControllerDismisser: ObservableObject {
    var host: UIHostingController<AnyView>?

    func dismiss() {
        host?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

This way, I can just initialize this controller as a normal UIHostingController

`let screen = RootViewController(rootView: MyView())`

**Note** : I used an `.environmentObject` to pass the object to my views that needed it. This way no need to put it in the initializer, or pass it through all the view hierarchy

Answer (score 3):

iOS 15 and above

```
struct MyView: View {
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Dismiss") {
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Simple call to `dismiss()` does not work for me. Probably because I do not have `NavigationView` in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether `isPresented` will be connected to `View`'s `UIHostingController` in a future version.  You should [submit feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com) about it.

In the meantime, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56880640/467209) for how to access a UIViewController from your `View`s.

Then, you can just do `self.viewController?.dismiss(...)`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be self.presentingViewController?.dismiss() ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue presenting an instance of `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

In this scenario, the UIDocumentPickerViewController is presented modally (`sheet`), which slightly differs from yours -- but the approach may work for you as well.

I could make it work by conforming to the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` protocol and adding a callback to dismiss the View Controller inside the `Coordinator`.

Code example:

> SwiftUI Beta 5

```
struct ContentProviderButton: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isPresented = true
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "folder").scaledToFit()
        }.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) { () -> DocumentPickerViewController in
            DocumentPickerViewController.init(onDismiss: {
                self.isPresented = false
            })
        }
    }
}

/// Wrapper around the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.
struct DocumentPickerViewController {
    private let supportedTypes: [String] = ["public.image"]

    // Callback to be executed when users close the document picker.
    private let onDismiss: () -> Void

    init(onDismiss: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.onDismiss = onDismiss
    }
}

// MARK: - UIViewControllerRepresentable

extension DocumentPickerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIDocumentPickerViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> DocumentPickerViewController.UIViewControllerType {
        let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: supportedTypes, in: .import)
        documentPickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        documentPickerController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return documentPickerController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: DocumentPickerViewController.UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {}

    // MARK: Coordinator

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
        var parent: DocumentPickerViewController

        init(_ documentPickerController: DocumentPickerViewController) {
            parent = documentPickerController
        }

        func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
            // TODO: handle user selection
        }

        func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
            parent.onDismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the Environment Variable directly to dismiss:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

var body: some View {
    Button("Dismiss") {
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```