# SwiftUI Alert not presenting in View contained in UIHostingController in iOS14?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, alert, uialertcontroller, uihostingcontroller

I have a SwiftUI View that is presented by UIKit and is contained within a UIHostingController. This View has a button that should trigger an Alert to be presented. My implementation is straightforward. Here is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var presentAlert = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Delete") {
            presentAlert = true
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $presentAlert) {
        Alert(
            title: Text("Are you sure?")
        )
    }.padding()
  }
}
```

In iOS15 and above it works perfectly fine. However, my project has a minimum deployment target of iOS14 and it doesn't work in iOS14. Does anyone know of any work arounds?

I think this is caused by the same issue that prevents presentationMode from dismissing a SwiftUI View contained in a UIHostingController in iOS14. [Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57190511/dismiss-a-swiftui-view-that-is-contained-in-a-uihostingcontroller)