# Navigate left instead of right in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to present a view within a NavigationView by sliding to the left instead of right (right is the default), is there a modifier to accomplish this in SwiftUI?

Below is a minimal example, where would the modifier go to navigate left instead of right??

Thank you

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(Text("activate"), destination: NewView())
        }
    }
}

struct NewView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("New View")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446820/15372665)?

Comment: Here is customisation. You can change direction : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65868820/14733292

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: How to present a FullScreenCover Sideways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65868660/swiftui-how-to-present-a-fullscreencover-sideways)

Comment: These are for .overlays, I am looking for a modifier to make a NavigationView push left instead of right

Comment: How does this have no answers! Wow!