# SwiftUI add overlay to entire screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a popup menu, similar to `.menu()` modifier that we have in SwiftUI. I managed to create the modifier and it is working fine.

**Problem:** The issue I have is that I am *unable to have an overlay extend to the entire screen* when the menu is displayed. Here's what I get when I try to overlay it (show in blue)

The reason for the problem is that I've a `TabView` which is wrapped in a parent `NavigationView`.

[image]

**Menu modifier:** Here's the modifier that I've created to show popup menus.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PopupMenu<MenuContent: View>: ViewModifier {
    
    let menuContent: MenuContent
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    // Number crunching to limit menu size to 2/3rd of the screen
    private let paddingRatio: CGFloat = 0.33
    private let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> MenuContent) {
        _isPresented = isPresented
        menuContent = content()
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            // The content to show menu on
            content
            if isPresented {
                ZStack {
                    // Overlay to hide background - blue color is just to accentuate the issue
                    Color.blue
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isPresented.toggle()
                        }
                    // Actual menu rectangle
                    VStack {
                        HStack() {
                            Spacer(minLength: paddingRatio * screenWidth)
                            menuContent
                                .padding(regularPadding)
                                .background(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: regularCorner)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .shadow(color: darkGray.opacity(0.3), radius: 24, x: -4, y: 12)
                                )
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.trailing, regularPadding)
                    .padding(.top, 2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func popupMenu<MenuContent: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> MenuContent) -> some View {
        self.modifier(PopupMenu(isPresented: isPresented, content: content))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

So it's apparent that you have a `NavigationView`. So in that case, use `.overlay(popupMenu())` to overlay the menu over the existing `NavigationView`

for example,

```
NavigationView {
    //Some content
}
.overlay(popup(_,_))
```

and in you `popOver` View, make sure to add the `.ignoresSafeArea()` to the `Color` view as follows

```
Color.blue
   .ignoresSafeArea()
   .onTapGesture {
       isPresented.toggle()
    }
```

Comment: That is a bit tricky since each tab has it's own menu and putting an overlay in the parent view means communicating from all child views on what to show - which is something I want to avoid!

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69342575/10229223 check this out!

Comment: @amintorabi That seems interesting. Although the problem is solved for now, but I'll surely give it a try!

Comment: @SiddharthKamaria how did you solved that

Comment: @AjaySinghMehra I didn't. Back then, I kept the modifier on the top-most view and communicated with the child views using `Binding`s. It was tedious but it worked. Now that we have `.presentationDetents([.medium])` in iOS 16+ it is easier to create overlays of whatever size that you need.